# Are there any complementary tools for the info command?

Tags: command-line, info

I've been using `man` for a while and know there commands like `apropos` or `whatis` that refer to man pages.

But, are there any equivalent of theses or some complementary tools of the same sort for texinfo tools?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, doesn't exist any complementary tools for `info` command. But if you want something like how `whatis` is for `man`, you can create your own 'tools'. For example, you can create some shell functions (like an alias):

```
about () { info $1 2>/dev/null | sed -n 6,8p; }
```

or, maybe better:

```
inf () { info 2>/dev/null | grep "* $1:" | sed 's/ \+ /\t/g' | cut -f2; }
```

Some outputs:

```
$ about () { info $1 2>/dev/null | sed -n 6,8p; }
$ #some outputs for 'about' function defined above
$ about ls
The `ls' program lists information about files (of any type, including
directories).  Options and file arguments can be intermixed
arbitrarily, as usual.
$ about cp
`cp' copies files (or, optionally, directories).  The copy is
completely independent of the original.  You can either copy one file to
another, or copy arbitrarily many files to a destination directory.
$ about yes
`yes' prints the command line arguments, separated by spaces and
followed by a newline, forever until it is killed.  If no arguments are
given, it prints `y' followed by a newline forever until killed.
$
$ inf () { info 2>/dev/null | grep "* $1:" | sed 's/ \+ /\t/g' | cut -f2; }
$ #some outputs for 'inf' function
$ inf ls
List directory contents.
$ inf cp
Copy files.
$ inf cut
Print selected parts of lines.
$ inf grep
Print lines matching a pattern.
$ inf sed
Stream EDitor.
```